# Java "Cannot find symbol" again

Tags: java

I've been given two java files (Main class (Practica1) and another class (Matriz2x2)). Both are in the same folder.
The main class instances the class I've been given, and this is where the "cannot find symbol" error pops out. 
The class Matriz2x2 compiles.

I won't give details of each class (methods, etc...) so, briefly, the Matriz2x2 class goes like this:

```
package mx.unam.ciencias.icc;

public class Matriz2x2 {

    private double a;
    private double b;
    private double c;
    private double d;

    public Matriz2x2(double a, double b,
                     double c, double d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d;
    }
}
```

And this is the main class:

```
package mx.unam.ciencias.icc;

import java.util.Random;

public class Practica1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();

    Matriz2x2 m = new Matriz2x2(r.nextDouble() * 100,
                                r.nextDouble() * 100,
                                r.nextDouble() * 100,
                                r.nextDouble() * 100);
    }   
}
```

This is the tantrum:

```
jose@jose-ThinkPad-T420:~/practica1/src/mx/unam/ciencias/icc$ javac Practica1.java
Practica1.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Matriz2x2
location: class mx.unam.ciencias.icc.Practica1
        Matriz2x2 m = new Matriz2x2(r.nextDouble() * 100,
        ^
Practica1.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Matriz2x2
location: class mx.unam.ciencias.icc.Practica1
        Matriz2x2 m = new Matriz2x2(r.nextDouble() * 100,
                          ^
Practica1.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Matriz2x2
location: class mx.unam.ciencias.icc.Practica1
        Matriz2x2 n = new Matriz2x2(r.nextDouble() * 100,
        ^
Practica1.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Matriz2x2
location: class mx.unam.ciencias.icc.Practica1
        Matriz2x2 n = new Matriz2x2(r.nextDouble() * 100,
                          ^
Practica1.java:37: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Matriz2x2
location: class mx.unam.ciencias.icc.Practica1
        Matriz2x2 i = m.inversa();
        ^
Practica1.java:43: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Matriz2x2
location: class mx.unam.ciencias.icc.Practica1
            Matriz2x2 id = m.multiplica(i);
            ^
6 errors
```

As you can see there are other errors about methods I did not include in the Matriz2x2 sample, but I didn't because all of them are about the same issue, it just can't find the Matriz2x2 class.
It may be simple but i just don't see any mistake they could have written in the code (besides a teacher wrote it) so I don't see why the main class is not compiling, everything seems to be right.

Comment: whether both the classes are compiled and present in the classpath

Comment: Are you using eclipse or another IDE? try reload the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to invoke `javac` from the root of your source hierarchy.

So do this:

```
 cd ~/practica1/src
 javac mx/unam/ciencias/icc/Practica1.java
```

This way, the compiler knows where to look for the Matriz2x2.java file.

Java requires that the directory structure reflects the package name. So since these classes are in the `mx.unam.ciencias.icc` package, the compiler expects them to live in the `mx/unam/ciencias/icc` subdirectory of the current directory. But by making the current directory the subdirectory, you're confusing the compiler.

An even better solution would be to write a build script (Ant) or use an IDE.

Comment: @JoséCasillas: Accept the answer instead!

Comment: Sorry but how do I do that?

Comment: There should be a faded checkmark below the vote count. Click it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have compiler your Matriz2x2 class first before you try to compile the Practical class.